# Sort by contiguous digits as a single number

Tags: awk, sed, sort

A command outputs this:

```
file_0
file_1
file_10
file_11
file_12
file_13
file_14
file_15
file_2
file_3
file_4
file_5
file_6
file_7
file_8
file_9
```

How can I use awk or some other posix tool to actually sort it by the contiguous digits as a single number:

```
file_0
file_1
file_2
file_3
file_4
file_5
file_6
file_7
file_8
file_9
file_10
file_11
file_12
file_13
file_14
file_15
```

In general it should also work in case the digits is inside the file name, e.g.:

```
file_0.txt
file_1.txt
file_10.txt
file_11.txt
file_12.txt
file_13.txt
file_14.txt
file_15.txt
file_2.txt
file_3.txt
file_4.txt
file_5.txt
file_6.txt
file_7.txt
file_8.txt
file_9.txt
```

Comment: it's not in [posix sort](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sort.html) but both GNU and FreeBSD's `sort` support the `-V` or `--version-sort` option, which is a "natural sort" of numbers embedded within text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sort -nt '_' -k2
```

Output:

```
file_0
file_1
file_2
file_3
file_4
file_5
file_6
file_7
file_8
file_9
file_10
file_11
file_12
file_13
file_14
file_15
```

or:

```
file_0.txt
file_1.txt
file_2.txt
file_3.txt
file_4.txt
file_5.txt
file_6.txt
file_7.txt
file_8.txt
file_9.txt
file_10.txt
file_11.txt
file_12.txt
file_13.txt
file_14.txt
file_15.txt
```

Tested with FreeBSD and GNU coreutils implementations of `sort` but
would not work with `busybox` implementation.  All options used are
specified by
[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html).

Comment: I see that option in the man page now! It was not clear at all to me at first.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
output | awk '{print gensub("[^0-9]*","","g")  " " $0 }' | sort -n | awk '{$1=""; print $0}' | sed 's/^ //g'
```

This isn't the most elegant solution but it works.

Answer (score 1):

The answer(one of them, I'm sure) is:

```
sort -t _ -k 2 -g [filename with names+numbers or piped from another command with | - both situations will work ]
```